# Minimize the code for on click listener

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am bored of implementing `View.OnClickListener` in my every activity. I need a method which could easily do it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating `abstract class` and `extend` it to all your activities. Usually know as **Base Class**.

Here is the code:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public void attachClickListener(int... views){
        for(int i = 0; i<views.length;i++){
            findViewById(views[i]).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {}

}
```

Keep both methods in your base class and override it from your activity class extended by the base class.

`attachClickListener` method will loop through all the IDs you will send as argument in your activity class.

Here is the code for your activity class:

```
@Override
attachClickListener(R.id.yourViewFromXml1, R.id.viewFromXml2, R.id.viewFromXml3 );
```

you can add infinite IDs.

```
@Override
OnClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId())
    case R.id.yourViewFromXml1 : // do your stuff;
                                break;
    case R.id.ViewFromXml2 : // do your stuff;
                                break;
}
```

Comment: Woow. Awesome. Best Solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use view injection, this way you can simply write the method and declare it as the onClick of some view on your layout.

See - [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/), or [RoboJuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Then use

```
@OnClick(R.id.submit)
public void submit(View view) {
  // TODO submit data to server...
}
```